# Rails compile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working from this tutorial:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Everything is fine until step 5.2.  When I change:

```
<%= form_for :post do |f| %>
```

To:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
```

I get a compile error:

> C:/Development/Rails/blog/app/views/posts/new.html.erb:1: syntax
>   error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND ....append=  form_for :post,
>   url: posts_path do |f| @output_buf...

The lines are both pasted from the tutorial. Sadly, there are no comments for the tutorial so I can't see if anyone has had the same problem. This is my first time using Rails at all.

Looking at the docs for `form_for` hasn't revealed a solution.

Comment: You're likely on Ruby 1.8.7. is that what you see when you run `ruby -v` ?

Comment: Just so you know, rails 4 has dropped support for ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Turns out I was on 1.8.7.  I upgraded and all is now well.  Will give you the answer credit, @JesseWolgamott if you want to post it below.  Unless there's a way to do it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error was with the colon on "url: posts_path", the problem is you were on version 1.8.7.

the hash syntax in 1.8.7 was `:key => value`, whereas it can usually be shortened to `key: value` in Ruby 1.9 +

If you are on Rails 3.2, you can switch to the hashrocket style `:key => value`. But if you are using Rails 4, you should upgrade to Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= form_for :post, :url => posts_path do |f| %>
```